# Bug in Firefox 30.0 autocomplete when using translate3d property?

Tags: css, firefox, autocomplete, autofill, translate3d

I've noticed Firefox doesn't display in the right place the autocomplete suggestions of form inputs when using the form inside an element with the css3 property `translate3d`.

Here's a picture in which the form container is using the following values:

```
transform: translate3d(0px, -3652px, 0px);
```

[image]
[Large image](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/3994560/3332654/db154f9e-f7e9-11e3-853f-01fbe1bab5f2.jpg)

**You can reproduce it here:**
http://jsfiddle.net/a2X72/2/

(if it doesn't autocomplete anything, send the form once for Firefox to record the values)

This bug doesn't take place in other browsers such as Chrome, Opera or Safari.

Comment: i had the same issue but the only fix i could find was to disable autocomlpete for now :(

Comment: The error should be gone by now. I was able to reproduce the error with FF31, but now with 35.0.1 the error is gone.